# StringBuilder thread safety

Tags: c#, ado.net, thread-safety, stringbuilder

I have written an extension method for SqlCommand to execute a batch of commands, which I have called ExecuteBatchNonQuery. This works fine. I have changed to return the messages output, to do this I had to create a method which is called from InfoMessage. It appends to a stringbuilder which I have had to make static. I am worried that this stringbuilder is not thread safe. I have to use a static, is there any way I can make it thread safe, or is there an alternative?

```
internal static class SqlCommandHelper
{
    private static readonly StringBuilder StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    internal static string ExecuteBatchNonQuery(this SqlCommand cmd, string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = cmd.Connection;
        conn.Open();
        conn.InfoMessage += MyConnectionInfoMessage;
        string sqlBatch = string.Empty;
        sql += "\nGO"; // make sure last batch is executed.
        StringBuilder.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (string line in sql.Split(new string[2] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                if (line.ToUpperInvariant().Trim() == "GO")
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlBatch;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlBatch = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    sqlBatch += line + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return StringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static void MyConnectionInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder.AppendLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your StringBuilder should be a local variable. You can use Lambda expressions to achieve this:

```
internal static class SqlCommandHelper
{
    internal static string ExecuteBatchNonQuery(this SqlCommand cmd, string sql)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        SqlConnection conn = cmd.Connection;
        conn.Open();
        conn.InfoMessage += (sender, e) => { sb.AppendLine(e.Message); };
        string sqlBatch = string.Empty;
        sql += "\nGO"; // make sure last batch is executed.
        sb.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (string line in sql.Split(new string[2] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                if (line.ToUpperInvariant().Trim() == "GO")
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlBatch;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlBatch = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    sqlBatch += line + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```